# Assign a method returning a specific implementation of T to a Func<T> variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics, unmanaged, func

I want to assign a method returning a specific implementation of the generic type parameter to a value `Func<T>`. T is constrained as unmanaged. And the Func will be used to fill a list.

The plan was to find the type T using a check `(typeof(T) == typeof(int)`, but the code does not compile.

```
public static List<T> CreateSimulationList<T>(int amount, Func<T> simulator = null)
    where T : unmanaged
{
    if (simulator == null)
    {
        //this sends an error: "has the wrong return type"
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int)) { simulator = FillWithZeroInt; }

        //this sends an error: "has the wrong return type"        
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(float)) { simulator = FillWithOneFloat; }
    }

    List<T> list = new List<T>(amount);
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        list.Add(simulator());
    }
    return list;
}

private static int   FillWithZeroInt()  => 0;
private static float FillWithOneFloat() => 1f;
```

Interestingly Rider does not report the issue inside the IDE. But Unity compiler does:

```
'MyImplementationStruct SimulateA' has the wrong return type.
'MyImplementationStructB SimulateB' has the wrong return type.
```

I got the reason from [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67483604/setting-a-funct-generic-inside-a-method-where-t-is-unmanaged-and-interface?noredirect=1#comment119278375_67483604) (thanks @canton7)

> The problem of course is that the typeof check is a runtime check, but
> the compiler needs to assert at compile-time

And if I declare the generic type and pass the function directly it works.

```
//this code works
var generatedList = CreateSimulationList<int>(10, FillWithZeroInt);
```

I would like to infer the type of T at compile time and assign a default method, or find any other way to avoid setting `Func<T>` inside the method parameters, and without boxing.

Thank you for reading this.

Comment: What are the types of `SimulateA` and `SimulateB`?

Comment: They return their respective structs. IE the first is `public static MyImplementationStruct SimulateA();`. I added them to the questions.

Comment: I'm surprised Rider is fine with that -- [The C# compiler certainly isn't](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetE+UkEAbMhAAyIDKAlgLYCuANgIYAuApgIIAUAlNrlhi5hyAOyIAdowYBufjgC+8xMoTIALIgCyAHgAqAPl6ZlwkAFZ9BxAGdajVgHsATogC8k6XKEicVAGaIXCwAngAObI7+XHo87h6hEVFcBKQ8fD6+gr6+dvTMLC7ulPYFnN45iEqZVbAKQA==)

Comment: `NativeList<int> currentUsed` ?? what is `list`? I can't honestly see how this code compiles

Comment: And from the first comment I understand that they might not be inferred, because in theory I might just exchange them in the code, but if I exchange them it would be totally wrong.

Comment: (The problem of course is that the `typeof` check is a runtime check, but the compiler needs to assert at compile-time that you can assign a method returning `MyImplementationStruct` to a `Func<T>`, and the compiler can't see into the runtime check)

Comment: Yea. I totally see that now, thanks @canton7. Is there any way I can achieve it without the typeof?

Comment: You can get around it by forcing a run-time conversion -- `simulator = new Func<T>(() => (T)(object)SimulateA())` -- but that will box each instance of `MyImplementationStruct`

Comment: Ok, but still how do you expect to return a `NativeList<int>` when the return type of the method is `NativeList<T>` ?

Comment: Thanks again, that would work, but boxing would not be a valid choice in my end. If that's the only option I would prefer to type it during the call and pass the method directly.

Comment: @Jamiec. Sorry, I'm following all comments and I corrected only part of the typo. It is a `NativeList<T>` as the return type and not a `NativeList<int>`.

Comment: This all hints to me that you're not showing us the _actual code you're using_ but a kind of mock up of it. Which probably masks the actual problem.

Comment: @JackMariani In future, make sure that you only post code which you have run and which you have confirmed reproduces your issue. If we can't run the code you posted, it's much less likely that we'll be able to help

Comment: @Jamiec The actual problem is clear in this case -- see my first link

Comment: @JackMariani Yeah I'd definitely follow that approach. `typeof(T) == typeof(Something)` is almost always code smell

Comment: @canton7 in this case yes, maybe. In most cases trying to mockup the problem in complex cases such as this just presents a different problem.

Comment: You should be able to cast, but you'll need a *triple* cast: `simulator = (Func<T>) (object) (Func<MyImplementationStruct>) SimulateA;`. (Note that a [mcve] would make this quicker for me to test...)

Comment: Yea, I see that now. Previously I thought that the interface and the unmanaged (or even Unity NativeList) restriction might be a source of the issue and I was conflicted if to add the entire thing. In the end I thought adding too much data was too confusing. Now I see that the core issue was not there, it was just getting T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, this has a bit of a design smell to it - using matching against specific types within generic methods is *usually* not ideal. I acknowledge that occasionally it's what's required though.

You can get this to work via casting... you need to cast to the concrete `Func` type to start with (or use another form of delegate initialization), then cast to `object` to basically stop the compiler from thinking it knows what will be valid, then cast to `Func<T>`. Here's a complete example:

```cs
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var func1 = CreateFunc<int>();
        var func2 = CreateFunc<string>();
        Console.WriteLine(func1);
        Console.WriteLine(func2);
    }
    
    static Func<T> CreateFunc<T>()
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
        {
            return (Func<T>) (object) (Func<int>) Int32Func;
        }
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
        {
            return (Func<T>) (object) (Func<string>) StringFunc;
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    static int Int32Func() => 0;
    static string StringFunc() => "";
}
```

Another alternative would be to use a lambda expression and casting the result of the method call to `T`. Again, you need to cast to `object` before casting to `T`:

```cs
if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
{
    return () => (T) (object) Int32Func();
}
if (typeof(T) == typeof(string))
{
    return () => (T) (object) StringFunc();
}
```

Note that *that* will involve boxing every time it's called if `T` is a value type, whereas the casting of the delegate itself won't.

Comment: This answer my question. I do not like the triple casting and I agree on the code smell. If there's no way to avoid that, then I'll follow the road of setting directly the method in the parameters of each call.

Answer (score 1):

Jon has already posted half of what I was going to post, so I won't duplicate his effort. However, I do want to add to that the suggestion that, inasmuch as I 100% agree with his note about "design smell" and "not ideal" (to put it mildly IMHO), I would propose that you should break your implementation into type-specific methods.

In other words, rather than making the method generic, just make two methods that have the signatures you want to handle:

```cs
public static NativeList<MyImplementationStruct> CreateSimulationListA(int amount, Allocator allocator,  Func<MyImplementationStruct> simulator = null)
{
    simulator = simulator ?? SimulateA;

    NativeList<T> list = new NativeList<T>(amount, allocator);
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        list.Add(simulator());
    }
    return list;
}

public static NativeList<MyImplementationStructB> CreateSimulationListB(int amount, Allocator allocator,  Func<MyImplementationStructB> simulator = null)
{
    simulator = simulator ?? SimulateB;

    NativeList<T> list = new NativeList<T>(amount, allocator);
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        list.Add(simulator());
    }
    return list;
}
```

You could even reduce the repetitive code, and still support scenarios involving other types, by keeping the generic version but not allowing that parameter to be optional nor null:

```cs
public static NativeList<MyImplementationStruct> CreateSimulationListA(int amount, Allocator allocator,  Func<MyImplementationStruct> simulator = null)
{
    return CreateSimulationList(amount, allocator, simulator ?? SimulateA);
}

public static NativeList<MyImplementationStructB> CreateSimulationListB(int amount, Allocator allocator,  Func<MyImplementationStructB> simulator = null)
{
    return CreateSimulationList(amount, allocator, simulator ?? SimulateB);
}

public static NativeList<T> CreateSimulationList<T>(int amount, Allocator allocator,  Func<T> simulator)
    where T : unmanaged, IMyInterface
{
    NativeList<T> list = new NativeList<T>(amount, allocator);
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        list.Add(simulator());
    }
    return list;
}
```

Since generic type inference wouldn't work in the missing-parameter scenario anyway, you must have been calling the method with an explicit type parameter, so customizing the call site to call the non-generic methods by their individual names shouldn't be a hardship.

The above reflects the fact that the code doesn't really seem to be generic to start with, so trying to make the method into generic was a mistake. Better to hard-code the types into non-generic methods, and leave the generic part for the scenario where the method can truly be generic.

Comment: I totally agree with this solution. Only con is that it creates different methods and I would like to re use the same one, declaring a different type parameter.